# How to store obj file in javascript for later use?

Tags: javascript

I am using the THREE library in JS and I want to be able to upon page load, store a remote obj file in the browser, so that later on when the user performs the action that need the obj file, I can save time because no network traffic.  The files are from 1 to 4 Mb.

To open that object file, I am using the [Three ObjLoader.load](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#examples/loaders/OBJLoader) function, which expects a URL as the first parameter.

So, where would I store in the browser this obj file so that later I can use it in `ObjLoader.load`?

Comment: if it's small enough and can be stringified, you can try the LocalStorage, but it's limited to 5MB I think

Comment: @JeremyThille if I store it in localStore, I can't pass it to that function because is not a URL, right?

Comment: Well you can do something like `ObjLoader.load( localStorage.getItem( "obj" ) )` I guess